# Can I use features like "Use count" in Collection Instance?

Tags: geometry-nodes, particles, instances

Enable *Particle > Render > Use Count*
And on the this image I set

```
Cube: 2
Cone: 3
Sphere: 21
```

[image]

Is it possible to set this in Geo node?

[image]

Comment: you can use the *instance index* to pick which instances goes on which point. this could be used to set a number of each instance.